# How to say "turnoff" in Russian

Tags: перевод

Turnoff is a word that is used when you've suddenly loose interest in something.
For instance, a woman goes on a date with somebody and this somebody get drunk too much. Than she can say something like "Sorry, but your behaviour was total turnoff".

Intuitively this is a very common concept but I'm failing to think of any good match in Ruassian. "Разочарование" is a different thing. What else? "Как отрезало" sounds like something actually more relevant but it's difficult to construct the whole phrase.

Comment: Неясно, в чём затруднение. Есть много слов в русском языке, чтобы выразить конец отношений, как они были прежде. Крышка, конец… «Извнини, но после этого… полный аут» Что касается концепции — она распространённая, но слишком отвлечённая от воспринимаемого напрямую. Совсем необязательно такими концепциями выражаться. «Интерес», «к чему-то»… О таких вещах надо составлять суждения и сохранять их в памяти, чувствуете? Чтобы потом накопленное напрямую забирать. Проще (по-русски) обратиться к тому, что можно напрямую замечать: те же отношения, например. А остальное приложится, догадаться-то нетрудно.

Answer (score 6):

I'd go with *охладеть* (or *охлаждение* if a noun is needed), though some people may think that it belongs to XIX century.

Another word which certainly comes to mind is *отвращение*, because it almost literally coincides with *turnoff*. Unfortunately it has too strong connotation with *disgust*, so one may want to choose some less insulting word.

Of course there are more options, such as *стал противен*, *омерзителен*, *неприятен*, *перестал для меня существовать* or just *разонравился*, for example.

Comment: nice attempt though )